# Does anyone have any information regarding J.V. Jones "Sword of Shadow" series?

Tags: sword-of-shadows

The *Sword of Shadows* series is a fantastic Fantasy book series, and highly under rated. It started in 1999 or 2000 with *A Cavern of Black Ice*, with the last installment, *Watcher of the Dead*, please having come out in 2010. However, the next book, *Endlords* has had no information out on it in years.

I was curious if anyone else may have kept following the author or have any new information on when this next book may be available.

Comment: Chapter 1 available online here; https://www.patreon.com/posts/endlords-chapter-21772146

Comment: Thank you! I've been waiting on this for years!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of October 2018, the book is (allegedly) *in process* and a short first chapter has been written and posted online.

> Read an excerpt from ENDLORDS Chapter One. https://www.patreon.com/posts/21772146
>
> <sub><sup>Via [Twitter](https://twitter.com/julievj/status/1047196692741668864?lang=en)</sup></sub>

From what I can tell, the writer has been in financial crisis for much of the last few years and has taken to other projects such as editing books and writing a potboiler in order to make ends meet. There are also (not so subtle) indications from her [twitter account](https://twitter.com/julievj/status/1118018227181735936) that she's been suffering from writer's block.

If you want to get this one off the ground faster, I'd suggest chipping in a few pennies and sending her an email of encouragement.

Comment: The writer's block would explain a lot, in terms of story. The financial issues even more so. Still... a decade seems to be a long time for a series that seemed to see such relative success and a dedicated fan base.

Comment: “writing a potboiler”. I’m not familiar with this idiom, and a cursory Google search isn’t helping. What does it mean?

Comment: @Thunder [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potboiler) says it’s a bad work of writing just to make ends meet for the writer.